# how to update the already inserted data(table format) in a database by using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is how to update the changed value in a database i tried it with alert it print the value correctly in the design page but when i tried to update in the database...please help me to fix this error..Below i have attached the screenshot of my error[image: screenshot]

code  i am using for update:

```
 public function Bill_Update($data)
 {
  data = $this->input->post();
  $count = count($data['Product_Code']);
  for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 
 $entries[] = array( 
    array(
  'billno' =>$this->input->post('billno'),
  'Product_Code'=>$data['Product_Code'] 
   [$i],
  'Prdtname'=>$data['Prdtname'][$i],
   'Qty'=>$data['Qty'][$i],
    'rate'=>$data['rate'][$i],
      'billdate'=>$newDate,
         'amount'=>$data['amount'][$i]
         ),
         );
    }
   $this->db->update_batch('salesitem', 
    $entries,'billno');
```

Comment: check iteration. make sure the number of iteration in for loop is the same as the number of data to be updated

Comment: There is a Syntax Error. `data` instead of `$data`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function Bill_Update($data)
{
   $data = $this->input->post();
   $count = count($data['Product_Code']);
   for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
       $entries[] = array(
           'billno' =>$this->input->post('billno'),
           'Product_Code'=>$data['Product_Code'][$i],
           'Prdtname'=>$data['Prdtname'][$i],
           'Qty'=>$data['Qty'][$i],
           'rate'=>$data['rate'][$i],
           'billdate'=>$newDate,
           'amount'=>$data['amount'][$i]
         );
   }
   $this->db->update_batch("salesitem", $entries, "billno");
}
```

Comment: Syntax Error in second example `data` instead of `$data`

Comment: I think you need to update this line $this->input->post('billno') to $data['billno'][$i];

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: billno

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1949

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\application\models\User_model.php
Line: 1161
Function: update_batch

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\application\controllers\Inventory.php
Line: 36
Function: Bill_Update

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once this is my error page

Comment: in your salesitem table  billno column is there?

Comment: can you share salesitem table structure so i can help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182330/discussion-between-esakkichandra-and-sachin).

Comment: # Name Type  
 1 idPrimary int(11)   
 2 billdate date                            
        3 billno int(255)                                   
      4 Product_Code int(255) 
     5    Prdtname varchar(255)    
    6    Qty int(255)                                
     7         rate int(255)   
    8   amount int(255) this is my table

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
<?php

public function Bill_Update($data)
{
  $data  = $this->input->post();
  $count = count($data['Product_Code']);
  for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 
    $entries[] = array(
                    'billno'       => $this->input->post('billno'),
                    'Product_Code' => $data[$i]['Product_Code'],
                    'Prdtname'     => $data[$i]['Prdtname'],
                    'Qty'          => $data[$i]['Qty'],
                    'rate'         => $data[$i]['rate'],
                    'billdate'     => $newDate,
                    'amount'       => $data[$i]['amount']
                );
  }
  $this->db->update_batch('salesitem', $entries,'billno');
}
```

I also checked above comments getting error undefined **billno**, can you please let me know what is the column name inside salesitem table for bill no column, according to me we are passing wrong column name, please ensure that.

Comment: # Name Type 
1 idPrimary int(11) 
2 billdate date 
3 billno int(255) 
4 Product_Code int(255) 
5 Prdtname varchar(255) 
6 Qty int(255) 
7 rate int(255) 
8 amount int(255) this is my table